# Javascript inserted from Plugin pointing to wrong location

Tags: plugins, javascript, references

This has happened time and time again on multiple sites. When it happens, it forces me to start with a fresh install of WordPress to get around it.

The most recent example is on the WP Forms Lite plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpforms-lite/

On the plugin, I enable recaptcha, and then instead of pointing to Google for the javascript file:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js

It points to my local site:
/recaptcha/api.js

This has happened to me on multiple WordPress installs, I feel like on every plugin that requires an external javascript file.  For example, on a WooCommerce plugin site, I enabled Stripe payments, and instead of referencing:
https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js

The site will reference:
/checkout.js

WordPress will randomly remove all javascript URL references to external sites.

Is there a manual way to fix this? If I deactivate all plugins, delete them, then install the plugin, activate, it does not fix the issue. I have to completely delete WordPress on my server and reinstall to fix.

Comment: Have you tried fresh install with a default theme and only plugins you've mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, the only way to fix is to start with a new install of WordPress. I reinstall the template, the plugins, etc. The reason I asked the question is to avoid having to reinstall and reactivate everything to get the site working. I would like to know if I can at least modify something manually to get the site / plugin to point to the correct javascript file location.

Comment: I am not sure you hear me. Does fresh install with no other plugins behave the same?

  When you reinstall themes and plugins you don't reinstall the database which contains all settings and so on. It does not matter you overwrite *.php files.